# Django model-database changes

Tags: database, django

I have a legacy database that I'm using in an app in Django.  I used the django admin functionality to generate the models.py file from the existing tables.

If I make changes to the models, such as adding a `unique_together` constraint to models, are the changes managed by Django, or do I have to somehow apply said model changes to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for django to detect changes, you will need to use a third party migration tool called `south`. Now, since you've already committed meaning you ran `python manage.py syncdb`, you will need to delete the table and start over.

This is how you do it (after you have deleted your table):

1. Install south using `pip install south`
2. Add south to installed apps, and make sure it comes before all the other apps that you created
3. Run this: `python manage.py schemamigration --inital <your app name>`
4. Run this: `python manage.py migrate <your app name>`
5. Run this: `python manage.py syncdb` <- last time you will need to run it :)

Hope this helped.

Comment: nice answer. HOwever you dont need the `syncdb` at the end.

Comment: @karthikr: You do if you're doing all of this for the first time.